# Change cell value within a row depending on other cell values within same row

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro enable spreadsheet to help me keep track of support tickets that I am currently working on in my engineering position.

I have 16 columns that provide information about each support ticket, such as Date, Serial Number of the device, Device location and so forth. A new row is a new support ticket.

Let's say we are working with row 50.

Column E represents the status of the device for which the ticket has been opened. Such as Deployed, Configure, and Floor Install.

Column F represents the device type such as Exalogic, and Exadata

Column K represents whether or not I need to create a special ticket depending on the value of E "OR" the value of F. Column K's values can be either yes or no.

This is what I have thus far and it does work with the column E range.

```
Dim rng As Range 
Dim cellE 
Dim cellF 

If Not Intersect(Range("E12:E100"), Target) Is Nothing Then 
Application.EnableEvents = False 

For Each rng In Intersect(Range("E12:E100"), Target) 

    Set cellE = Range("E" & rng.Row) 
    Set cellK = Range("K" & rng.Row) 

    If Range("E" & rng.Row) = "Configure" Then 
        Range("K" & rng.Row) = "No" 
    ElseIf Range("E" & rng.Row).Value Like "*Floor*" Then 
        Range("K" & rng.Row) = "No" 

    Else 
        Range("K" & rng.Row) = "" 
    End If 

Next rng 
Application.EnableEvents = True 

End If
```

However, if I try adding in the F range, nothing works:

```
If Not Intersect(Range("E12:E100"), Range("F12:F100"), Target) Is Nothing Then 
Application.EnableEvents = False 

For Each rng In Intersect(Range("E12:E100"), Range("F12:F100"), Target) 

    Set cellE = Range("E" & rng.Row) 
    Set cellF = Range("F" & rng.Row) 
    Set cellK = Range("K" & rng.Row) 

    If Range("E" & rng.Row) = "Configure" Then 
        Range("K" & rng.Row) = "No" 
    ElseIf Range("E" & rng.Row).Value Like "*Floor*" Then 
        Range("K" & rng.Row) = "No" 
    ElseIf Range("F" & rng.Row).Value Like "*Exa*" Then 
         'Range("K" & rng.Row) = "Not Needed"
    Else 
        Range("K" & rng.Row) = "" 
    End If 

Next rng 
Application.EnableEvents = True 

End If
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not jujst use range E12:F100 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better explain my comment:

column E never intersect Column F.

so your intersect will always fail, you are currently looking for the intersection of the three ranges, when you want the intersection of target with either of the two so you could use:

```
If Not Intersect(Range("E12:F100"), Target) Is Nothing Then 
Application.EnableEvents = False 

For Each rng In Intersect(Range("E12:F100"), Target) 
    Dim curRow as long
    curRow = rng.Row
    Set cellE = Range("E" & curRow) 
    Set cellF = Range("F" & curRow) 
    Set cellK = Range("K" & curRow) 

    If cellE  = "Configure" Or cellE.Value Like "*Floor*" Then 
        cellK  = "No" 
    ElseIf cellF .Value Like "*Exa*" Then 
         'cellK  = "Not Needed"
    Else 
        cellK  = "" 
    End If 

Next rng 
Application.EnableEvents = True 

End If
```

If you needed non contiguous ranges you could also use

```
`Intersect(Range("E12:E100","F12:F100"), Target)`
```

as this combines the two ranges into one

```
If Not Intersect(Range("E12:E100","F12:F100"), Target) Is Nothing Then 
Application.EnableEvents = False 

For Each rng In Intersect(Range("E12:E100","F12:F100"), Target)
    Dim curRow as long
    curRow = rng.Row
    Set cellE = Range("E" & curRow) 
    Set cellF = Range("F" & curRow) 
    Set cellK = Range("K" & curRow) 

    If cellE  = "Configure" Or cellE.Value Like "*Floor*" Then 
        cellK  = "No" 
    ElseIf cellF .Value Like "*Exa*" Then 
         'cellK  = "Not Needed"
    Else 
        cellK  = "" 
    End If 

Next rng 
Application.EnableEvents = True 

End If
```